# Salesforce security: Is it just marketing claim?

Tags: web-services, security, salesforce

In their [security statement](http://www.salesforce.com/company/privacy/security.jsp) you can read:

> Salesforce.com utilizes some of the most advanced technology for Internet security available today.

When you read the rest of the article nothing really shows that this claim. Use of SSL is very common how is this “most advanced”? What proves that their server follows best security practice as [this story](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/news/2011/02/anonymous-speaks-the-inside-story-of-the-hbgary-hack.ars) reveals even a specialized security company doesn't follow them?

So how do you get insurance that their code is really robust? What tools? If you use these tools to fake attacks they may retaliate for example so it's not very practical.

This is not targeted especially at salesforce this is more general question about SAAS or PAAS. If you use such services to integrate with your site, how can you ensure that the security is handled correctly knowing that you cannot trust only claim ? This is a big question you need to answer Corporate Management when you choose such solution. How can you answer if they want proofs ?

Comment: Whilst I understand your point, it's not completely clear what your question is.  Are you looking for them to clarify what they actually use to back up this statement.  Are you looking for adherence to your companies security requirements, Either way howver this would seem to be a question best asked to Salesforce.com itself.  Interestingly, in the UK, the ASA have just started monitoring and enforcing claims made on websites to stop widely inaccurate claims.

Comment: ok i have updated the question. This is not targeted especially at salesforce this is more general question about SAAS or PAAS. If you use such services to integrate with your site, how can you ensure that the security is handled correctly knowing that you cannot trust only claim ? This is a big question you need to answer Corporate Management when you choose such solution. How can you answer if they want proofs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question. How can we trust any Saas claims, let alone their security ones? I think it comes down to trust and marketing. In the end, since the software is not hosted in our servers, we don't know for sure if they really are secure. We can't force guys like SalesForce to make guarantees either. I would love to see a third party website that reviews all these SaaS applications, and report on their downtime, security, issues, etc.

Comment: I'd like to but it should not be like standard and poors paid by the brokers to review the financial companies :)

Comment: that's kind of a spooky response, considering where I work LOL.